# Git rebase chain master->featureA->featureB. Something changed in master, why rebase featureB again?

Tags: git

I had a master branch and started featureA branch from there.
Then I started featureB branch from featureA.
Then I added one commit with one file for master
Then I rebased featureA from master
But after that I got tons of conflicts  when tried to rebase featureB from featureA due to some reason.
Why and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Why do you need to do rebase there and back? Do it by one direction. Or even better - avoid rebase, but rather do merge if there are multiple branches coming from same one. Rebase is more "advanced" feature, and should be used carefully.

Comment: It's a requirement in my team unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Remember, branches are only "labels" for one commit that move automatically forward when new commits are added. They always point to the latest commit which has been created for this branch. Each commit points to its parent (or its parents in the case of merge commits).

```
  e--    master
 /
a-b-c-d
    ^ ^
    | `- feature-b
    `--- feature-a
```

`git rebase target` is shorthand for `git rebase target current-branch`, which in turn is shorthand for `git rebase --onto target target current-branch`, i.e. "take all commits reachable from `current-branch`, but not reachable from `target` and re-apply their changes as new commits to `target`".

Running `git rebase master feature-a` will rebase commits `b-c`, but `git rebase master feature-b` will rebase `b-c-d`.

If you rebase `feature-a` and *then* `feature-b`, then Git assumes `feature-b` contains 2 commits (`b`, `c`, and `d`). There are several options to avoid or resolve this:

- Rebase only `feature-b` and then recreate `feature-a` on the newly rebased commits
- Use the explicit invocation of rebase: `git rebase --onto new_target old_base branchname` (e.g. `git rebase --onto master old-feature-a feature-b`)
- Use interactive rebase mode and drop all commits which have already been applied: `git rebase -i target feature-b`
- Run regular rebase and in case of conflict check if the changes have already been applied. If so, skip the commit: `git rebase --skip`

NB. It is always good to create backup branches before doing stuff like this, e.g. `git branch backup-feature-b feature-b`